# Terraform Autoscaling - Detailed monitoring turned on by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I use autoscaling with launch configuration, detailed monitoring seems to be **enabled** by default.
When I create EC2 instances directly using the `aws_instance` resource, detailed monitoring seems to be **disabled** by default.

Is there a reason for this difference? If I do not need detailed monitoring (data being sent every 1 minute) for my application, can I safely set it to false in the launch configuration used by Autoscaling?

I have read the following links but unable to find any additional information about the monitoring levels.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#enable_monitoring

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an AWS API thing as mentioned in the [AWS User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html#enable-as-instance-metrics):

> By default, basic monitoring is enabled when you create a launch configuration using the AWS Management Console and detailed monitoring is enabled when you create a launch configuration using the AWS CLI or an API.

Comment: Thanks for the link in AWS User Guide. Detailed monitoring do have a cost (around $2.10 for each instance). We did not know that we had enabled detailed monitoring in our dev/test envs by using autoscaling/launchconfiguration with terraform! I don't know why AWS API does that. We think basic monitoring would be sufficient for our needs and so we will disable detailed monitoring.

Comment: If you found that this answer solved your problem then it would help others if you [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so that people know that this solution at least worked for you. You will also receive 2 reputation for accepting an answer.